# Regexp with carrriages in notepad++ on windows

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have several .txt files I must modify:

every

```
\(
\blabla
```

must become

```
\begin{equation*}
\blabla
```

notepad++ does find `\\(` when I use `\\(\r`. But when I input `\\(\r\blabla` it does not find anything. I am a noob at regexp.

Comment: Because you aren't escaping the second `\\`, it is interpreting it as `\b`, a word boundary and tries to find `labla`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match newlines, you need a `\n` in some places, and `\r` in others. I'm not sure about which to use when either, but if the one doesn't work, try the other. In your case, use this:

```
\\(\n\\blabla
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Extended Search" option in "Search Mode" section. This will detect \r correctly. Enter search string as `\(\r`.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you should use something like `(?:\r\n|[\r\n])` to match any of the three most common line endings, `\n` (Unix), `\r\n` (DOS/Windows) or `\r` alone (pre-OSX Mac).  In this case I think it's safe to assume the line endings are all `\r\n` or all `\n`, which you can match with `\r?\n`.

But you have a better option: `\v`, the vertical whitespace shorthand.  It will match a carriage return or linefeed, but not spaces or tabs.  This works for me in NPP v6.5.5:

```
\\(\v+\\blabla
```

I'm assuming you want `\\b` to match a backslash followed by `b`, not a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match any line break, use `\R`. And, as Alan Moore said, to match a backslash `\` followed by a `b`, use `\\b`:

```
\\(\R\\blabla
```

`\R` matches `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n`